# Django 1.6: sort objects by highest values

Tags: python, django

I've a list of doctors that have a like attribute. I want to list them in my template in descending order based on number of likes they have.

Here is the template where I need to show them

```
{% for doc in doctors %}
                <h2><a href="/docprofile/{{doc.id}}/">{{doc.name}}</a></h2>
                <h3> {{doc.specialization}}</h3>
                <h4> {{doc.clinic.name}}</h4>
                <h4> {{doc.clinic.address}}</h4>

                <div class="like">
                  <img class="like" src="/static/meddy1/images/like.png">
                  <p>{{doc.likes}}</p>
                </div>

       {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(doctors, 20) #Show 20 doctors per page
    page =  page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        doctors = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        doctors = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        doctors = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    d['doctors'] = doctors
    d['paginator'] = paginator

    return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by):

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-likes')
```

You can also define the [default ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) in Model Meta class:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-likes']
```